# Needing formula for a compounding number multiplied by a value (Not anually)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Looking for very simple compounding math.

I have a number, for example, 5000. This number increases by a percent, for simplicity sake, let's say it increases by 100%, it does that 3 times. The final result for that should be 40000. 5000*2 then *2 then *2.

The question is, how do I make this happen with math on a spreadsheet. Preferably Google Sheets. Something I can use variables in for the percentages and times it increases.

This is not for annual compounding interest or any of that. I just need plain and simple compounding numbers.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you seek something simple as:

```
=A22*2^3
```

[image: 0]

which could be also written as:

```
=A22*2*2*2
```

in terms of percentage it would be simply:

```
=(A22*B22)*2^3
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you a ton! Can't believe how hard it is to find this online!